# HMENU/GMENU render pages.media field

Tags: typo3

I am migrating typoscript from TYPO3 6.2 ELTS to 7.x ELTS.

Following code works in 6.2 thanks to activateContentAdapter which is removed in TYPO3 7. https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/7.2/Breaking-66034-DropContentAdapter.html

Is that possible to still use HMENU/GMENU or should I rewrite it totally other way?

```
lib.navigation.socialmedia = HMENU
lib.navigation.socialmedia{
wrap = <ul>|</ul>
special = directory
special.value = 123
1 = GMENU
1{
    NO{
        wrap = <li class="first">|</li>|*|<li class="middle">|</li>|*|<li class="last">|</li>
        altImgResource.import = uploads/media/
        altImgResource.import.field = media
        altImgResource.import.listNum = 0
        ATagTitle.field = subtitle // title
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you still could use `GMENU` but you need to change the filehandling. As mentioned files are no longer just copied to `uploads/media/` but there is a file-handle (`sys_file`record) whose uid is used everywhere.

First substitution: `treatIdAsReference`

This is a usage for rendering an icon of the first media entry in a text menu (`TMENUITEM`) before the text **(1)**.
The rendering is inside of the `FILES`object which represents an (possible) array. SO it might be a little bit complicated to insert it into an `IMGRESOURCE`object **(2)**.

if you just want the resource adapt the `renderObj`, as this example renders the image (cropped) and generates an `<img>`tag.

```
NO.stdWrap.prepend = FILES 
NO.stdWrap.prepend { 
  references { 
    table = pages 
    uid.data = current:originalUid // current:uid
    fieldName = media
  } 
  renderObj = IMAGE 
  renderObj {
    file { 
      import.data = file:current:uid 
      treatIdAsReference = 1 
      width = 150c 
      height = 150c 
    } 
    altText.data = file:current:alternative
    titleText.data = file:current:title
    params = class="menu-img" 
    stdWrap.typolink.parameter.field = uid
  } 
  maxItems = 1 
}
```

**(1)** with the options of CSS3 and HTML5 and the preferred way of accessibility you have multiple ways to use a clean text menu without 'hiding' text in graphics.

**(2)** you might use `altImgResource.cObject = FILES` and render an `IMGRESOURCE` instead of an `IMAGE`.

---

meanwhile (since TYPO3 9) you have `menu_processor`s and you would render the menu with fluid, where you 'navigate' through the pagetree with all properties of each page, including images.

Comment: I tried something similar but unfortunatelly this does not work... altImgResource is of data type imgResource (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/7.6/en-us/MenuObjects/Gmenu/Index.html) so it will not render FILES (altImgResource = FILES)...

Comment: of course. I changed my answer to the original snippet and some further explanations.